# Does The electron get absorbed by nucleus in a conductor when they collide with the atoms

Tags: electricity, solid-state-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, conductors

If my question is incorrect then please also mention the correct thing which happens to them.

Comment: No, they just bounce off small perturbations in the potential.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do we mean when we say an electron collides with a molecule or atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335679/what-do-we-mean-when-we-say-an-electron-collides-with-a-molecule-or-atom)

Comment: There are some isotopes that can become more stable if the nucleus absorbs an electron from a K orbital, but this is a rare event.

Answer (score 0):

No. An electron getting absorbed by a nucleus is called Electron Capture, or sometimes K Capture, but this is a nuclear reaction mediated by the Weak force, i.e. rare, and usually with electrons from the innermost K shell, not quasi-free electrons that form a current. Typical energies are 10s to 100s of keV.

Instead, electrons that form a current move in the conduction band. These energy levels only have energies of eV. So the electrons simply bounce around the conductor. This effect is what makes the Ohmic resistance of a conductor increase with temperature: hotter means more atom movement means more bouncing means more electrical resistance.